# How do I get the full uri of the .js file I am executing?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I need to get the uri of the .js file presently executing. I need this to create a web worker, passing in the full uri of the web worker js file.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966941/how-to-get-the-uri-of-the-js-file-itself) doesn't work because my file is loaded by requireJS and therefore the script executing is require.js.

What I need is a way to give the full uri to a specific .js file. The uri must use the same root that the .js file executing is in so the browser does not see it as a cross domain request. If there is a better way to accomplish this than working from the uri of the executing .js file, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

`requirejs` has some magic arguments that you can request - among them is [`module`](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/19a98167858db65342a269ba76f06e3be152210e/require.js#L584-597):

```
define(["module", "other", "dependencies"], function(module, other, deps) {
  var whereAmI = module.uri;
});
```

Comment: I tried this and for a uri of http://localhost:62178/client/scripts/layout/test-layout.html module.uri has a value of "./_@r2.js"

Comment: I'll need a bit more information to debug - one, is `test-layout.html` what you are loading or is it the page on which you are loading your app? Two, are you using `r.js` to concat all of your scripts together or are you loading them async?